# Cron job does not execute according to time schedule

Tags: php, cron, crontab

Consider the following cron job:

```
* 22-23 * * * /usr/bin/curl -u username:paswword http://api.example.com/api/test2.php
```

Now, according to this, the cron job must run every minute starting from 22h00 (UTC) but it doesn't. It starts before that time and also not for the full hour. So I wrote the execution time to a database table, just to see what's going on. Here is what I get:

[image: database entries screenshot]

The `systemDateTime` represents when the cron job executes. As you can see, it only executed 6 times and it started about 6 minutes before the scheduled time.

Is this system configuration related? The cron job is on a Apache shared server. Am I missing something or what?

**Update**: I use the following PHP code to get the system date time and my timezone date time:

```
$systemDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dateNow = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('GMT+2'));
$zoneDateTime = $dateNow->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Note that although it doesn't address your pre-start concern, `* 22-23 * * *` is actually two hours and should run from 22:00 to 23:59 inclusive

Comment: What does the following command produce on your system, please: `date; date +'%Z %z'; date --utc`. I'm also wondering what timezone your `crontab` is configured to use

Comment: Your first comment is helpful. Where do I execute that command? I tried in cronjob and got email with: /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file.

Comment: How do I see what timezone crontab is configured to use? I have a shared server and use cpanel 110.0.20

Comment: "_Where do I execute that command_" - in a shell - in a terminal session. (It will fail under `cron` because `%` is a special character there)

Comment: "_How do I see what timezone crontab is configured to use?_" - something else that's troubling me. In the image you've posted there's a `zoneDateTime` and a `systemDateTime`. (a) which one has the correct time for you, (b) which country are you in?

Comment: I'm in South Africa. Our zone is GMT+2. The cron job is working now. I don't know why it's working correctly now and it even uses my time. I created a cron job with command service crond restart. Could that be it? I'm not sure if it did execute - I'm not sure if I can run commands like that in a cron job. All I know, for sure, is that I can call a script in the cron job command. zoneDateTime and systemDateTime comes from php code. You can see that in my Update Note.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151101/discussion-between-clint-william-theron-and-chris-davies).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the timezone in the command seems to do the trick. Here is the new cron job:

```
* 22 * * * TZ=GMT+2 /usr/bin/curl -u username:password http://api.example.com/api/test2.php
```

Also, I'm not sure why it only executed 6 times with the first cron job but it's working fine now.